# WCF authentication with multiple providers

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, security, authentication

There is the following design: the back-end implemented as WCF, the public front site and two intranet sites (all three talking to the back-end). I believe that authentication on the sites is not enough (i.e. passing ClientID to WCF in each request as a parameter) and i want to protect my back-end (WCF) with authentication to perform double-check and have `PrincipalPermission` on the methods with roles specified.

I'm sure that identity names from both providers do not cross (public logins are digits only and the intranet will be something like 'DOMAIN\Login'). The front site uses forms auth and its provider returns `GenericPrincipal`. The intranet sites use Windows auth and i have `WindowsPrincipal` attached to `Page.User`.

Is it possible to configure WCF to use two membership providers (custom one that the front site uses and Windows) out of the box, without writing another custom code? Is it important how my WCF is hosted? Currently it's windows service. Do i need to switch to IIS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so - you can have only one membership provider. But you can have a custom provider that can authenticate against two different stores based on credentials presented. For example, it can check if user name is like domain\login then try against active directory otherwise try against web site provider.

Yet another idea is to have two different end points for the service. Each will be configured with specific provider. Service implementation would remain same - inside, you have to go for claim based authorization. Check this article for more info: http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ClaimsBasedSecurityModel

Comment: Excellent article, the best i've read so far! I didn't know that each end point can be configured to use specific provider so your idea looks like good solution to me. Thanks!

Comment: @UserControl, there is also part2 of the article, just realized that part1 didn't have the link. Here's it: http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ClaimsBasedSecurityModel2